# Pointwise convergence of a sequence of trigonometric polynomials with bounded number of nonzero terms

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I asked yesterday on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/643623) a question and received no answer. Since I'm very interested in an answer, I'm reposting it here:

"Let $k$ be a fixed integer, and $\mathcal{F}$ the set of trigonometric polynomials with at most $k$ nonzero terms. Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{F}$ converging pointwise (on $\mathbb{R}$) to some continuous function $f$. Then there is the following dichotomy

- if $f \in\mathcal{F}$ then $|f_n−f|_{L_{\infty}} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
- if $f \notin \mathcal{F}$ then $|f_n−f|_{L_{\infty}} \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Question : Can the second case actually happens? I've not been able to provide any example so far..."

Comment: Dear @js21: I sincerely think one should wait more that just one day before reposting on MathOverflow from Math.StackExchange.

Comment: Ricardo Andrade: I may have been confused by the fact that my question was lost somewhere on the 50th page of the list of the "newest questions" on Math.Stack Exchange, and thus seemed unlikely to be answered. I apologize if posting on Mathoverflow was inappropriate.